My Azure web app (rest node api ) works with a curl request in terminal but not with frontend or Thunder Client

I have a REST API deployed on Azure.
When I'm making requests, other than curl, it is sending a 404 response, but when I make a request with curl the resource gets created and everything works. I also specified Acess-Control-Allow-origin as "*", though I am not getting the response that I am expecting, except when I use curl.
I tried to invoke the API through fetch and also with my Swagger API docs, but neither worked. However, when I copy the curl request generated by the Swagger docs and paste it in the terminal, then it gets executed and the resource gets created in the DB.

You need to enable CORS in your backend using cors package. if you are using express in node.js use app.use(cors());

if possible can you share your code.

I am also getting the same error for my express web app without CORS but after using cors in my code it worked for me.
My swagger UI

Error:

Below code I added cors package and used in express which worked for me.
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors'

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(cors())

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  res.send("weclome to express app")
})


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});

OUTPUT:

